# A problem from BDMO 2017.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

If we can write a number as $a^b$ then we call that number LAL number where both $a, b$ is greater than $1.$ Again, the sum of two LAL numbers is a LAL number.

After
which value, every number is a LAL number?

Comment: $2^2+2^3$ is not a LAL number in general $2^n+2^{n+1}$ is never a LAL number. So in general you can always find a number such that there is a number bigger then that which isn't LAL.

Comment: The  question lacks precision. Can we use only integers or any real? LAL number is defined as either a $a^b$ or a sum of LAL numbers, or only $a^b$, with the supposition that the sum of such number can be writen the same way (wrong for integers)?

Comment: I had the same question as you @kingW3. Adding two LAL no. is not a LAL no. Plus we can always find a no. bigger than that which is LAL.

Comment: The question should probably be that the number is LAL if it's equal to $a^b$ where $a,b>1$ or if it's a sum of two LAL numbers which makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways a number can become LAL.  Either it is a power on its own; or it inherits LAL when it is the sum of two other LAL numbers.

A) $4$ is LAL, so is $4+4, 8+4$, and by induction any multiple of $4$.

B) $9$ is LAL, so is $9+4, 13+4$, and by induction numbers $1$ more than a multiple of $4$.

C) $9+9$ is LAL, so is $18+4, 22+4,$ etc

D) $9+9+9$ is LAL, etc
$A,B,C,D$ cover all numbers greater than $23$.

Comment: Damn bro thats the best answer I can get, thanks mate.